# "Error: Symbol TMath is not defined in current scope"

Tags: c++, root-framework

Here is my macro:

```
#include "TMath.h"
using namespace std;

void GettingStarted()
{

    Double_t x = TMath.PiOver2();
    cout << pow(x,2);
}
```

As you can tell from the function name, I'm new to ROOT (and C++ in general, so I apologize if this is really sloppy). How can I fix this error, and (more importantly) why am I getting this error? Also, if anyone know any good tutorials for ROOT 5.34, that be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TMath` is a namespace, so you need to use the scope-resolution operator `::` rather than the class member access operator `.` to access names declared inside it:

```
Double_t x = TMath::PiOver2();
```